# Kotlin silence remove from audio file

Tags: android, kotlin

- In my app i have silence remove from audio file which selected from device.
- I tried this but not get output properly but get noisy/currept audio file as output.
- I need proper output file which play after remove silence

```
fun removeSilence(data: ByteArray, sampleRate: Int): ByteArray {
        val shortArray = ShortArray((data.size / 2))

        for (i in data.indices step 2) {
  // shortArray[i / 2] = (data[i].toInt() and 0xFF) + (data[i + 1].toInt() shl 8) // its give crash of indexoutofbound so i do like below temporary

            val l1 = (data[i].toInt() and 0xFF)
            val l2 = if(data.size > i) {
                try {
                    if (data.size <= i)
                        (data[i].toInt() shl 8)
                    else
                        (data[i + 1].toInt() shl 8)
                }catch (ex: Exception){
                    (data[i].toInt() shl 8)
                }

            }else {0}

            shortArray[i / 2] = (l1+l2).toShort()
        }
        
        val silenceThreshold = (SILENCE_THRESHOLD * sampleRate) / 1000
        var silenceDegreeCounter = 0
        val processedData: MutableList<Byte> = arrayListOf()
      
        for (i in shortArray.indices) {
            val currentSample = Math.abs(shortArray[i].toInt())
            Log.d("processedDataARR", "i=$i - currentSample=$currentSample - silenceThreshold=$silenceThreshold - SILENCE_DEGREE=$SILENCE_DEGREE")

            if (currentSample < silenceThreshold) {
                silenceDegreeCounter++

            } else {
                silenceDegreeCounter = 0
                processedData.addAll(shortArrayToByteArray(shortArrayOf(currentSample.toShort())))

            }
        }
        return processedData.toByteArray()
    }



  private fun writeAudioFile(data: ByteArray, filePath: String, sampleRate: Int? = null) {
       
        val file = File(filePath)
        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
        outputStream.write(data)
        outputStream.flush()
        outputStream.close()
        rawToWave(file,getFile("wav")!!)
    }
```